# Hive : inserting into multiple tables based on query result

Tags: hadoop, user-defined-functions, hive

I am trying to run a hive query to filter invalid records.  Here is what I am doing
1. Load the csv file into a single column table. 
2. define a UDF my_validation to validate each record
3. execute the query

```
from pgstg INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/tmp/validrecords.out'  
select * where  my_validation(record) IS NOT NULL
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE PGERR
select record where  my_validation(record) IS  NULL;
```

Here are my questions:
a. Is there a better way to filter invalid records;
b. Does the  my_validation UDF run twice on the whole table ? 
c. what is the best way to split a single column to multiple column.

Thanks much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1) If you have custom validation criteria UDF is probably the way to go. If I were doing it, I would create an is_valid UDF that returns a boolean (instead of returning NULL vs. not NULL).

2) Yes, the UDF does get run twice.

3) Glad you asked. Look at the [explode](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-explode) function available in Hive